# Regex to exclude minutes and seconds which are less than 6 minutes

Tags: regex, awk

I need help with the regex.
I have a file which has pods status including age

```
NAMESPACE      NAME               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
util           tomcat-4           0/1     Running            0               4m
util           tomcat-5           0/1     Running            0               125s
util           tomcat-6           0/1     Running            0               88s
```

Now I need to print the pods whose Age is greater than 6 minutes.
So in my output I should see the first 3 pods

I have been using this regex but its failing for any seconds and for minutes which has 0-6 digits like 15m

```
awk '$NF !~ /[0-6][ms]/ { print }' file.txt
```

Comment: You should probably create a custom script instead of just regex.

Comment: I think my other solution worked
cat test_pods.txt | awk '$NF !~ /^[0-6][m]/ { print }' | awk '$NF !~ /[0-9][s]/ { print }'

Comment: since you are using awk, you can write some logic. Not written to match your need 
`echo -e "a\t10s" | awk -F'\t' '$NF ~ /[0-9]+s$/ {v=substr($NF, 1, length($NF)-1); v=v+0; if(v>6) { print $0}}'
`

Comment: Could the age be greater than 6 minutes in seconds? eg `501s`?

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be what you want, using any awk:

```
$ awk '/m$/ && ($NF+0)>6' file
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
```

or maybe this if you can have a number of seconds greater than your target, e.g. `361s`:

```
$ awk '$NF*(/m$/ ? 60 : 1) > 360' file
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
```

Comment: I looked at the POSIX specification and could not conclude that `361s` in arithmetic context shall be interpreted as number 361. Is this POSIX?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes, it's POSIX. Under [Expressions in awk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02) - "A string value shall be converted to a numeric value ... by converting the initial portion of the string to type double representation as follows ... The sequence starting with the first digit or the <period> (whichever occurs first) is interpreted as a floating constant of the C language, and if neither an exponent part nor a <period> appears, a <period> is assumed to follow the last digit in the string."

Comment: and then in it goes on to say "An application can force an expression to be treated as a number by adding zero to it". It's a bit lengthier than that and IMO could be much clearer but it's saying that given the string `123foo` if you add `0` to it will be treated as if it were the string `123.` and converted to the number `123`.

Comment: Thanks, I probably missed the _initial_. And I agree that a simple example would help.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using 2 conditions here, if last field ends with `m` then check if its greater OR equals to 6 `OR` if last field is ending with `s` and its value is greater or equals to 120 then print that record.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} ($NF ~ /m$/ && $NF+0>=6) || ($NF ~ /s$/ && $NF+0>=360)' Input_file
```

Comment: your `+0` are in the wrong place

Comment: @jhnc, hey could you please do let me know more on this one, thank you.

Comment: consider `echo 33m | awk '{print $NF>=6+0}'; echo 33m | awk '{print $NF+0>=6}'`

Comment: @jhnc, ohh I got it, I need a strong coffee :)

Comment: @jhnc : then might as well make it `awk '{ print(6 <= +$NF) }'` - the extra zero in `x+0` is superfluous since `+x` achieves the same effect and it's cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- age field contains exactly one of `m` and `s`
- age greater than 6 minutes will never be specified as seconds (eg. `361s`)
- `6m` does not count as "greater than 6 minutes"

```
awk '$NF !~ /s|^[0-6]m/' file
```

If age like `361s` could occur, then:

```
awk '
    !( $NF~/m/ && $NF+0 <= 6 ) &&
    !( $NF~/s/ && $NF+0 <= 360 )
' file
```

`$NF+0` extracts the numerical prefix of `$NF` (probably using [strtod](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtod.html)) or returns 0

Comment: I had assumed printing the header was desired but, re-reading the question, that may not be the case

Answer (score 1):

If your time units can only be minutes (`m`) or seconds (`s`) you can first convert the age to seconds and test if it is larger or equal `6*60`:

```
awk '{a=length($NF)} NR>1 && substr($NF,1,a-1)*(substr($NF,a)=="m"?60:1)>=6*60' file
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have been using this regex but its failing for any seconds and for
> minutes which has 0-6 digits like 15m

I do not think regular expression is right tool for dealing with arithmetic like less than or greater than, but if you must use that AT ANY PRICE I suggest following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
NAMESPACE      NAME               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS        AGE
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
util           tomcat-4           0/1     Running            0               4m
util           tomcat-5           0/1     Running            0               125s
util           tomcat-6           0/1     Running            0               88s
```

and define task as finding lines where last column value is greater or equal `6m` then

```
awk '$NF ~ /^[6-9]m$/ || $NF ~ /^[0-9]+[0-9]m$/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
```

Explanation: I instruct GNU `AWK` to only print lines where last field is one digit from range 6-9 i.e. 6789 followed by `m` or (`||`) last filed is one-or-more digits followed by digit followed by `m`. Observe `^` and `$` to prevent partial match. **Disclaimer** this solution is based *solely* on your presented input.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner solution:

`perl -ne '{m/\s+([0-9]+)m$/; print if $1>6}' inputfile`

This prints

```
util           tomcat-1           0/1     Running            0               38m
util           tomcat-2           0/1     Running            0               15m
util           tomcat-3           0/1     Running            0               7m
```

You capture last column that is minute, and check if it's greater than 6. However, if I were you I would write a script for this.

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
cat test_pods.txt | awk '$NF !~ /^[0-6][m]/ && $NF !~ /[0-9]s/ { print }'
```

Comment: This code have few issues, though not sure if this worked with shown samples(didn't check it yet). Also we need not to use `cat` with `awk` code, `awk` could read Input_file by itself.

Comment: yes awk can read the file itself and my question is not about using awk with cat, I just took some dummy example. Its more about the regex :)